# xamdatagrid not available in datasource dropdown nor in customize control binding

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, infragistics

I'm trying to use the xamdatagrid option but when creating a new datasource I should have a choice in the dropdown for xamdatagrid which I don`t and then I should have the choice either in the customize window! I just created a new project WPF framework.4.72 on an SQL database! I also tried it on a local access database!

I'm new to Infragistics and am looking at the "Adding a Data Grid in WPF"  tutorial!

However I do see the xamdatagrid in the toolbox.

Comment: I would recommend you to download the _Infragistics WPF Samples_ from the Infragistics site. They include the **xamDataGrid SQL Data Binding** demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution which was to remove any nuget packages and simply add a xamdatagrid via the toolbox. This automatically adds the proper references which are different from the NuGet ones as they have a version number attached to them! After that the xamdatagrid will show up in the dropdown for the datasource!

I can now follow the tutorial (from 2013) as is! Now I can create a datagrid without a single line of code!

I had already downloaded the trial, but you still need to do the manual add for it to work!